# jQuery Ajax request error function issue

Tags: ajax, function

I'm making an Ajax request that works perfectly fine.  The issue I'm having is that I attached the "error" method onto the call and when I modify the URL to try to make it throw an error....I get no error.  Here is my code:

```js
function instagramAjax () {
  $.ajax ({
   url: "url that works",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(returnedData) {
    //my success code that works
   },//end success
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Error " + errorThrown);
   }
  });//end ajax request
 }//end instagramAjax function
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the url that you'd set?
This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

```
  window.MyCallback = function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    };

    function instagramAjax () {
            $.ajax ({
                url: "url that works",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'MyCallback',
                success: function(returnedData) {
                    //my success code that works
                },//end success
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    console.log(status, err);
                }
            });//end ajax request
        }//end instagramAjax function
```

or you can do it:

```
function instagramAjax () {
            $.ajax ({
                url: "url that works",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonp: 'MyCallback',
                success: function(returnedData) {
                    //my success code that works
                },//end success
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    console.log(status, err);
                }
            });//end ajax request
        }//end instagramAjax function
```

Comment: The url is for Instagram.  I tried the cross domain with still no luck: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/432935321/media/recent/?client_id=#########

Comment: The function will be called only if the request fails. And for external link, set crossdomain to true.

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/432935321/media/recent/?client_id=######### return a JSON, so, it will called on success function.

Comment: So you're saying datatype: "json" instead of jsonp?

Comment: I updated my publication with the correct use. You need to set the callback function to jsonp.